# How do I grep without leading whitespaces?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep, sed

I'm greping through a large codebase, and leading whitespaces and tabulation seem to be quite annoying. Is there any way to get rid of it?

```
grep -R "something" ./
```

E.g, instead of:

```
foo/bar.cpp:                       qwertyuiosomethingoi
foo/bar/baz.h:                          43rfsgsomethingdrfg
bar/bar.cpp:            1234edwssomethingczd
```

I want to get something like:

```
foo/bar.cpp: qwertyuiosomethingoi
foo/bar/baz.h: 43rfsgdsomethingrfg
bar/bar.cpp: 1234edwssomethingczd
```

Or better:

```
foo/bar.cpp:   qwertyuisomethingooi
foo/bar/baz.h: 43rfsgdrsomethingfg
bar/bar.cpp:   1234edwssomethingczd
```

Comment: Get rid of it where? In the output? In the search pattern?

Comment: @Ignacio, in output. Updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create test files

```
echo -e "\t   foo-somethingfoo" >something.foo
echo "    bar-bar-somethingbar" >something.bar_bar
echo "baz-baz-baz-somethingbaz" >something.baz_baz_baz
echo "  spaces    something  s" >something.spaces
```

produce full glorious colour :)

```
grep --colour=always "something" something.* | 
 sed -re  's/^([^:]+):(\x1b\[m\x1b\[K)[[:space:]]*(.*)/\1\x01\2\3/' |
   column -s $'\x01' -t
```

output (run it to get the colour).

```
something.bar_bar      bar-bar-somethingbar
something.baz_baz_baz  baz-baz-baz-somethingbaz
something.foo          foo-somethingfoo
something.spaces       spaces    something  s
```

---

Tested in `gnome-terminal`, `konsole`, `terminator`, `xterm`

Comment: good work! a little problem, though, you forget to match `\t` characters

Comment: `\t` ? ... It's not using `\t` for a seperator, it is using  $'\x01' (hex 01)... or do you mean something else?

Comment: I mean there may be leading tabulations `\t` as well as leading whitespaces `\s`

Comment: ... fixed. Changed ​` ` ​​ to `[[:space:]]` ... If you want to only consider TAB and SPACE, and not *all* whitespace, use this instead: `[ \t]`

Answer (score 14):

You can just eliminate them using `sed`

```
grep blah filename.foo | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'
```

That will remove the leading whitespaces from the output

Comment: This won't have any effect, since there are no spaces at the start of any line in the output.

Comment: Only relevant if grep is used with `-h`

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you're looking for pattern `re` (a basic regular expression) in one file, and you'd like to strip leading whitespace from all matching lines:

```
sed -n -e 's/^[[:blank:]]*//' -e '/re/p' thefile.c
```

(actually, this strips all leading whitespaces first, and then looks for the pattern, but the result is the same)

To post-process the `grep` output instead (as in your edited question):

```
grep -e 're' -- * | sed 's/:[[:blank:]]*/: /'
```

The pattern `[[:blank:]]*` matches zero or more spaces or tabs.

If you insert a tab instead of a space after the `:`, you additionally get some of the nice even indentation you requested.

Comment: Thanks, the last snippet works fine. Is there any way to preserve output color?

Comment: Colour? Call me old fashioned, but my terminal is strictly black and orange... (that's an "I don't know").

Comment: Use --color=always (assuming GNU grep) on the grep call.  The sed call doesn't remove the colors, it's grep itself that doesn't use color when the output doesn't go to a terminal (with the default of --color=auto).  "always" forces it to, well, *always* use color.

Comment: @Jurgen, thank you, but with `--color=always` this regexp doesn't work :/

Comment: Oh shucks, you're right.  That's because there are control sequences (for the color) between the colon and the whitespace.  You could put the escape sequences into the sed call (the sequence is, at least for a bog-standard vt100 emulation (xterm, screen, etc) "\033[m\033[K".  I think. ;D

Comment: The second option didn't work for me when I was outputting a line with a single leading space from a file (using `grep`).

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard grep accepts both `color` and `colour`. You can look at its help page

Comment: @Andrew I think you can grep one more time after sed to colorize the output again